# Twin primes paired

Tags: java, primes

This program is a basic attempt at finding a pair of twin primes each, before and after a given numerical value on the whole number line.The code looks good but is not giving any output and neither is it terminating post a run.I would like to know what is wrong with it.Thanks!

```
public class twin {

    public boolean prime(int num) { // function to check for a prime number

        if (num % 2 == 1 && (num % 3 == 2 || num % 3 == 1)) {
            return true;

        } else
            return false;

    }

    public static void main(String args[]) { // main
        int inp_num = 7; // given number too check for twin primes before or
                            // after it
        twin ob = new twin();
        int arr[] = new int[5];
        for (int x = inp_num; x > 0; x--) { // checking limit [o,inpnum)
            boolean b = ob.prime(x);
            if (b = true) {
                if (ob.prime(x - 2) == true) {
                    arr[0] = x;
                    arr[1] = x - 2;
                }

            }

        }
        for (int x = inp_num; x >= inp_num; x++) { // checking limit
                                                    // [inpnum,infinity]
            boolean b = ob.prime(x);
            if (b = true) {

                if (ob.prime(x + 2) == true) {
                    arr[2] = x;
                    arr[3] = x + 2;
                }

            }

        }
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
            System.out.println(arr[i] + "\t");

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: On a side note, I would check your `prime` method. Take for instance 55. It is not divisible by 2 nor 3 but it is certainly a composite number.

Comment: Is there any other problem,say, if I rectified this?

Comment: A way to check if a number is prime is either to do a sieve or go through a loop to the square root of a number and check divisibility that way

Comment: could you add as code block for the latter

Comment: See my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

```
for(int x=inp_num;x>=inp_num;x++){ //checking limit [inpnum,infinity]
```

this line of code will run indefinitely.

Also,

public boolean prime(int num)

this function will not check the prime correctly. I suggest you to look up some easy known way for checking primality, like [Eratosthenes sieve](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes)

Comment: I can add a break statement then

Comment: You could, but it is a bad practice. it's better to define the limits for your loop, ie set the max number you want to check

Answer (score 0):

**Regarding your** `boolean prime(int n)` **method:**

This method you use to go about finding a prime is wrong. Knowing that every number is the product of one or more primes, we can actually go up to the square root of `n` to make things simpler.

```
public boolean prime(int n) {
  if (n % 2 == 0) return false;

  for (int i = 3; i <= Math.sqrt(n); i += 2) {
    if (n % i == 0) return false;
  }
}
```

We need to check if n is divisible by 2 since any even number is composite; that is, it is divisible by a number other than one and itself.

We start at 3 since 1 is not a prime and we had already checked 2. We increment `i` by 2 each step because we are only checking the odd numbers.

Finally, we only need to go to the square root of `n` because every number, if composite, is guaranteed to have a prime factor that is less than or equal to the square root of said number.

**Regarding your loop** `for (int x = inp_num; x >= inp_num; x++) { // checking limit`**:**

This loop will not execute. Remeber in the beginning of the program you set `inp_num = 7`. Because the loop ending condition requires `x >= 7`, the condition is already met and therefore will not execute. If you want the loop to execute once, say

`for (int x = inp_num; x > inp_num; x++) { // checking limit`.

Answer (score 0):

```
int count = 0;
For(int a = 1; a <= num; a++)〔 if (num % a = 0)
        Count++;
    else
        Continue;〕
if (count == 2)
    System.out.println(num + "is a prime number ");
else
    System.out.println(num + "is a prime number); //this is to check whether number is prime.
```